# What are modular variables and modular momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, terminology

Yakir Aharonov et al. refer in their renowned recent paper on understanding the double slit experiment, that if applying the Heisenberg picture instead of the Schrödinger picture, and making use of *"modular momentum"* (modular variables) instead of "momentum" of the particles, the non-locality could be well described and understood. This way, within a double-slit experiment, the particle goes only through one of the slits. In addition, a nonlocal property originating from the other distant slit has been affected through the Heisenberg equations of motion. Under the assumption of nonlocality, uncertainty turns out to be crucial to preserve causality. Hence, a (qualitative) uncertainty principle can be derived rather than assumed.

However, the article requires the reader to know what *"modular momentum"* is.

May someone explain to me in a very comprehensive way, what in quantum mechanics *"modular variables"* and as an example *"modular momentum"* are?

Context:
*Finally making sense of the double-slit experiment
Yakir Aharonov et al.; PNAS June 20, 2017 114 (25) 6480-6485; [here](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.1704649114)*

Comment: There is one instance where you say "modulated" instead of "modular". Is this a typo or are the two terms used interchangably?

Comment: Modular variables in quantum theory https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00670008

Answer (score 1):

Regarding a particle's momentum we require such a variable to fulfill the following condition:

*The change of the variable after **many** collisions should be comparable  to its change after **one** collision, such that the associated changes in momentum could remain bounded.*

Such a condition requires a bounded function of momentum, hence we consider a variable $p$ with:

$$p= n\,p_0 + [p\pmod {p_0}]$$

while $n$ is an integer and the remainder $p\pmod {p_0}$ satisfies:

$$0\le [p\pmod {p_0}]<p_0$$

In contrast to a random or linear walk that would take place along an infinite straight line, the walk of modular momentum would be taking place along a circle.

Reference: Yakir Aharonov, Hugh Pendleton, Aage Petersen;
Modular variables in quantum theory;
October 1969; International Journal of Theoretical Physics; 2(3):213-230;  [>>> Article on ResearchGate](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/225861224_Modular_variables_in_quantum_theory)

Comment: " The change of the variable after many collisions should be comparable to its change after one collision, such that the associated changes in momentum could remain bounded."    Like the momentum of an electron moving in a magnetic field and gas?

Comment: @Pathfinder If the double slit experiment would be performed instead of photons with electrons analogous nonlocal equations of motion will result, satisfied by nonlocal modular momentum variables. I am not sure how far the nonlocality and complete uncertainty could be compared with what we know as "Landau levels" on the state of electrons in magnetic field. For constructing such analogy, the state equation in the Heisenberg picture to be compared AND the "potential" identified.